# How to merge StreamControllers of different types?

Tags: flutter

I need to merge Streams of different types:

```
enum ApiKeyLoadingState {Done, Error, Progress}
enum RegionsLoadingState {Done, Error, Progress}
enum IndustryLoadingState {Done, Error, Progress}

class TenderApiProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ApiKeyLoadingState apiKeyLoadingState;
  RegionsLoadingState regionsLoadingState;
  IndustryLoadingState industryLoadingState;

  static StreamController <ApiKeyLoadingState>streamApiKeyController = StreamController();
  static StreamController <RegionsLoadingState>streamRegionsLoadingController = StreamController();
  static StreamController <IndustryLoadingState>streamIndustryLoadingController = StreamController();
  var resultController = StreamGroup.merge([streamApiKeyController, streamRegionsLoadingController, streamIndustryLoadingController]);
}
```

I am getting error:

> The element type 'StreamController' can't be assigned to the list type 'Stream'

I am not sure that Streams should be `static`, but without static I am getting error:

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring your streams as `static` use `final` and then initialize the `resultController` in the constructor of `TenderApiProvider` like this:

```dart
class TenderApiProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  // ... some declarations are omitted for brevity
  final StreamController<ApiKeyLoadingState>streamApiKeyController = StreamController();
  // ... further declarations are omitted for brevity
  Stream<dynamic> result;

  TenderApiProvider() {
    result = StreamGroup.merge([streamApiKeyController.stream, streamRegionsLoadingController.stream, streamIndustryLoadingController.stream]);
  }
}
```

You can read more about `static`, `final` or `const` in [this article](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html).

Comment: @DaGarden, I am getting error: `'result' can't be used as a setter because it is final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'result' non-final`

Comment: yes! sorry I copied the wrong snippet from my editor. I fixed it. the result Stream cannot be `final` as the error message correctly states.